# Is it possible to place a breakpoint inside of a Jenkinsfile for debugging?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Right now sorting out a good workflow using Jenkinsfiles is a bit slow since I have to create a job, and run it from the UI in order to get feedback on whether or not it works.

I was wondering if there was a way to place a breakpoint inside of a Jenkinsfile that way I could toy around and get a feel for the libraries / methods / variables that are available.

Is this something that is possible? Or do I have to stick to my current process of editing a Jenkinsfile in the Jenkins UI and then re-running the build?

**--Edit--**

I've found a workflow that works a little faster than making changes through the UI. The SSH server within Jenkins exposes a command called `declarative-linter` and one called `replay-pipeline`. Now I just develop the script locally and rerun these commands after I make an edit.

So basically, my workflow is like this:

- Edit the script to my liking
- Run the lint check. I have jenkins setup in my ssh config file, so basically I run this using Powershell:

`gc Jenkinsfile | ssh jenkins declarative-linter`

- Run the newly changed script by replaying a pipeline build:

`gc Jenkinsfile | ssh jenkins replay-pipeline <name of my job with branch name>`

- Run the console command to tail the logs:

`ssh jenkins console <name of my job with branch name>`

All I did was wrap these lines into a PowerShell function and after I edit the script locally I run one command to perform all this to validate the change. It's definitely more complicated, but the turn around time is a bit faster than it was using the Jenkins UI, plus I get to edit the script using my favorite editor. Hopefully, in the future, there will be better tooling around debugging Jenkinsfiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the only way currently. Although I know that there requests for future additions in this direction ([Pipeline debugger](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34185)). Probably there are some options to debug this directly from Java, but this is not a trivial setup to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Add an user input

```
input message: "Continue?"
```

[pipeline input step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/),
[Read interactive input in Jenkins pipeline to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47080683/read-interactive-input-in-jenkins-pipeline-to-a-variable)