# taking user input from user jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

i need to take some variables from user as input in my jenkinsfile. For this purpose in have written following code.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
         stage ('Take Input') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def INPUT_PARAMS = input message: 'Please Provide Parameters', ok: 'Next',
                                        parameters: [
                                        input(name: 'ENVIRONMENT', description: 'Please select the Environment')]
                }
            }
         }
         stage('clone repository') {
             steps {
                 checkout scm
             }
         }
     }
}
```

In case of choices this code is working is fine but i need user to type his answer in textbox. But i upon running job i am getting following error.
[image]

please can someone help me achieving this.

Comment: It is an open issue on jenkins: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41662. Try to do the same with old UI, maybe that's just a blueocean plugin bug.

Comment: looks like duplicate of the below issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47080683/read-interactive-input-in-jenkins-pipeline-to-a-variable